# Scriptable Object is null when dragged to field inspector?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm a novice in programming / unity and trying to use scriptable objects, but having a hard time.
I'm trying to use SO as a way to store the base attribute data of players, monsters, etc.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
 
[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "New StatData", menuName = "Scriptables/StatData", order = 0)]
public class StatData : ScriptableObject
{
    [SerializeField] public float[] _stats;
 
    public StatData()
    {
        _stats = new float[(int)StatType.Num];
    }
}
```

The class is simple. Only has a float array(StatType is an enum).
So I made the SO in the project window under the Resources folder,
assigned all the values via the inspector,
and dragged it into the field in my StatContainer class, which deals with all attribute changes.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System;
 
public enum StatType
{
    MaxHP,
    MaxMP,
    Strength,
    Defense,
    Magic,
    Resistance,
    MoveSpeed,
    Num,
}
 
public class StatContainer : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] protected Stat[] _stats;
    [SerializeField] protected StatData _statData;
    void Awake()
    {
        Init();
    }
 
    void Init()
    {
        _stats = new Stat[(int)StatType.Num];
 
        for(int i = 0; i < _stats.Length; i++)
        {
            _stats[i] = new Stat((StatType)i, 0);
            _stats[i]._currentValue = _stats[i]._baseValue = _statData._stats[i];
        }
 
        _currHP = _stats[(int)StatType.MaxHP]._baseValue;
        _currMP = _stats[(int)StatType.MaxMP]._baseValue;
 
    }
}
```

I tried debugging, and in line 35 of the StatContainer class, the _statData itself is null.
I can see that it's referenced in the field in the inspector, but it's still null in debug.

I found out that if I use Resources.Load, no problem occurs.
But if I drag - drop the SO into the inspector, it's always null.

Is this not the way to use SO? or am I doing something wrong?

If I make an instance of the SO by ScriptableObject.CreateInstance,
it means that I have to assign all the values by script, and that's not what I want,
because I thought that the convenience of assigning the values in the inspector and drag-dropping or loading the SOs were a big part of using them.

It hasn't been long since I started programming and used unity, so I would much appreciate any enlightenment.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome, I realize you're doing this as an exercise to learn about scriptable objects, but, be aware that normally for something this extremely simple you'd just use PlayerPrefs. (just google PlayerPrefs., it's a line of code)

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into that.
But not knowing why this doesn't work really bugs me.

Comment: Never mind.
I was being stupid. I had another object with the StatContainer class

Comment: good one, enjoy

Answer (score -1):

I would answer this as a comment, but I don't have the reputation yet, as I am also pretty new. Could it be the that object you are referencing the script on is a prefab? Sometimes if you don't hit apply on the prefab, it just doesn't accept that you've referenced it in the Inspector field. That could possibly be the issue, but I have no experience with Scriptable Objects, so I could be absolutely wrong.

Comment: No, it's not a prefab. I'm afraid that's not the issue here